# Python Polars groupby variance

Tags: python-polars

I would like to compute the groupby variance of my polars dataframe. Maybe the reason is obvious but I don't know why it does not exists in the [groupby object namespace](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/groupby.html#groupby). Is there a workaround maybe?

`df.groupby("group_id", maintain_order=True).var()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `pl.all` to obtain your desired statistics for groups.  For example:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

nbr_rows_per_group = 1_000
nbr_groups = 3

rng = np.random.default_rng(1)

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group" : list(range(0, nbr_groups)) * nbr_rows_per_group,
        "col1": rng.normal(0, 1, nbr_groups * nbr_rows_per_group),
        "col2": rng.normal(0, 1, nbr_groups * nbr_rows_per_group),
    }
)

(
    df
    .groupby('group')
    .agg([
        pl.all().var().suffix('_var'),
        pl.all().mean().suffix('_mean'),
        pl.all().skew().suffix('_skew'),
    ])
)
```

```
shape: (3, 7)
┌───────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ group ┆ col1_var ┆ col2_var ┆ col1_mean ┆ col2_mean ┆ col1_skew ┆ col2_skew │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═══════╪══════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 0.999802 ┆ 0.99401  ┆ 0.017574  ┆ 0.021156  ┆ -0.042408 ┆ 0.0102    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ 1.031637 ┆ 1.029593 ┆ -0.053874 ┆ -0.037097 ┆ 0.004183  ┆ 0.080086  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ 0.941347 ┆ 1.006852 ┆ 0.029232  ┆ -0.023855 ┆ 0.049269  ┆ 0.074515  │
└───────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```